# How to override the Prestashop 1.7 Controller class

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

How can I override the default functionality of Prestashop 1.7 using the override feature

Answer (score 0):

To override the Prestashop controller class you have to create a separate file with the same name as the class name and extend it to the core class and put that file in to override folder.

For example: if you want to override the Product class located at

```
root/classess/Product.php
```

Create a file with the name Product.php in `root/override/classes/` folder.
Now create the Product class and extend it to ProductCore class

```
class Product extends ProductCore
{
    // put the functions and variables that need to be override
}
```

This is not compulsory to put all the content of ProductCore class into the override class. Just put the required functions that you want to override.

Note: Don't forget to clear the cache.